# Django + mod_wsgi - How to disable access to files outside of project folder?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to make more secure my django virtual host by disabling the access of files that do not belong to my project. So basically I'm looking for similiar like **"php_admin_value open_basedir"**.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a setting. As the [Django docs state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/), your code should not be in the docroot anyway:

> Where should this code live?
>
> If your background is in plain old PHP (with no use of modern
>   frameworks), you’re probably used to putting code under the Web
>   server’s document root (in a place such as `/var/www`). With Django, you
>   don’t do that. It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code
>   within your Web server’s document root, because it risks the
>   possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web.
>   That’s not good for security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as
>   `/home/mycode`.

The only thing that should be served is the wsgi file. So the rest of your files are safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Currently on my ubuntu desktop OS I store my project in **"/home/{myuser}/django/myproject"**, but I was still able to open and print out files like **"/home/{myuser}/secret.txt"**. What can cause this? Maybe because my user is administrator? Moving the project to **"/home/myproject"** would solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "open and print out" the files? How were you doing that? Also, you might need to post your Apache conf.

Comment: I'm not at home right now, I followed this tutorial to setup my vhost:
http://youtu.be/hBMVVruB9Vs?t=18m1s
"open and print out" - I meant that I was able to read the content of the file with my django app.

Comment: If files could be pulled from your home directory, you must have set DocumentRoot or an Alias directive in a way that a URL mapped to that directory. Plus, you must have then also told Apache it was allowed to serve up files from that directory using the Allow directive. One common mistake some people make is to throw away the default Apache configuration files and start over. That is a very bad idea, as the default configuration files are locked down and builtin defaults which would be revealed by ignoring the configuration files aren't.